# How can I map a click in Vim?

Tags: vim

I want to be able to click (or cmd+click on my Mac) on a function name in Gvim (or vim with `set mouse=a`) and have it run the command `:tag` to follow a ctag, but I don't know how to include a mouse click in a Vim mapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good place to start:

```
:help click
:help mouse
```

Perhaps something like this will work:

```
:map <RightMouse> :tag <CR>
```